# Is it possible to transmit more than 60Hz on a HDMI port?

Tags: display, hdmi, lcd, port, dvi

Is it possible to transmit more than 60 Hz to my LCD through the HDMI port on my laptop?

Somewhere I've read that I need to have a HDMI 1.4 cable to do that – but I haven't found anything like this sold.

Comment: What would you need that for? Why exactly would you need to feed your LCD something with more than a 60 Hz frame rate?

Comment: Because picture is not that sharp/crisp on 60 as it is on 75 or higher.

Comment: Hm, have you tried it with another connection or why do you think it is?

Comment: There can be bandwidth limitations without the right stuff, but the biggest problem I percieve to exist in most sitautions like this, reguardless of the device accepting a higher frequency (as token), there are only a handfull of LCD monitors/tvs capable of going past the 60 from end to end. so called "true 120" Vrses advertised refresh numbers. The complexity of the layers of BS is beyond the scope of the comment box :-)  Plus your laptop has to support it too. Unless your going to drop the resolution (decrease bandwidth)